# Best Practice of Extending Another's Theme?

Tags: views, theming

I have a standard theme developed by others that I would like to add a custom view template to.

Is it OK to just create a new "views-view-table--MYVIEWNAME.tpl.php" file in the theme directory itself?

Or, is there a way to create a "sub-theme" for my stuff that inherits everything from the original theme?

Thanks. Bill

Comment: Is the theme a custom theme developed for that website or is it a theme from drupal.org or some other paid theme or something?

Comment: A custom theme from our headquarters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly up to developer preference and specific use case but generally, if it is a custom theme, as in this case, you would add templates and modify css/template.php/etc. in the custom theme you already have.

If it is a theme from drupal.org or some other theme source, where updates for that theme may come in future, then it is best to [create a sub theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) of that theme (which you can do even if that theme is already a sub theme of another theme).

Comment: Thanks, I checked with the original theme developer and they basically said "go ahead and start with adding custom template files to our theme, then when you get comfortable with how it all works, migrate to a sub-theme."

Answer (score 0):

Templates are used by a theme on a most-granular-first basis.

This means that the system looks for something that is very specific to what is being rendered and then moves up the tree looking at more and more general options until it finds one that matches.

So a custom views-view-table--MYVIEWNAME.tpl.php file won't cause the standard views-view-table.tpl.php file to fail for other views with different names because they won't match that template file.

You can even make it more specific by name the display as well as the view if you have more than one display in your view.